# Flash messages not working in Rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

This is driving me insane.  I have a new `Rails 3.2.2` application for asset management.

Here is my controller:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def index
    respond_with(@assets = Asset.all)
  end

  def show
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @asset
  end

  def new
    @asset = Asset.new
    respond_with @asset
  end

  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    if @asset.save
      flash[:notice] = "Asset created successfully"
    end
    respond_with @asset
  end

  def edit
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @asset
  end

  def update
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    if @asset.update_attributes(params[:asset])
      flash[:notice] = "Asset updated successfully"
    end
    respond_with @asset
  end

  def destroy
    # tbd...
  end

end
```

Here is part of my `application.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
        <%= msg %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

However, the flash is always empty.  Even after the asset model updates successfully.

When I debug the flash object, this is what I get:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
used: !ruby/object:Set
  hash: {}
closed: false
flashes: {}
now:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. This [bug report](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5280) on Rails looks very similar to yours, so it might be worth updating to the latest version of Rails? (Bug was reportedly just fixed within past 24 hours)

Comment: OK, this is messed up.  I just created another asset (locations) and the flash messages work with it!  But not "assets".  I upgraded to Rails 3.2.2.  Did a bundle update.  And changed both controllers to be identical (well, except assets vs locations).  Why would it work on locations and not assets?  Ugh.

Comment: My guess is that 'assets' might be a reserved word in Rails 3.2. I couldn't find any evidence to back this up except for this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186183/routing-issue-with-rails-3